# Form not closing as it should

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-2007

I am automating an open source program written in Delphi. From the main form, I am performing the following loop:

```
for i := 0 to analysisNames.Count - 1 do begin
    currentAnalysisName := analysisNames[i];
    analysisID := DatabaseModule.GetAnalysisIDForName(analysisNames[i]);
    frmIIGraph.autoMode := true;
    frmIIGraph.ShowModal();
end;
```

As you can see, it opens a form called frmIIGraph. Inside that form, I must open another form, which I do with the following code:

```
procedure TfrmIIGraph.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if autoMode then begin
    events := DatabaseModule.GetEvents(analysisID);
    frmEventEdit.autoMode := true;
    frmEventEdit.OpenDialog(events,0,analysisID);
    frmEventEdit.ShowModal();
    //frmEventEdit.Close;
    SetFocus;
    ModalResult := mrOK;
    PostMessage(Self.Handle,wm_close,0,0);
  end;
end;
```

The form opened from the above method is called frmEventEdit. Within that form I am running this code:

```
procedure TfrmEventEdit.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if autoMode then begin
    btnRTK_CalcClick(nil);
    ModalResult := mrOK;
    PostMessage(Self.Handle,wm_close,0,0);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that the `PostMessage(Self.Handle,wm_close,0,0);` in the latter code works fine and closes the form, resuming the code on the `frmIIgraph` at `SetFocus;`. However, the `PostMessage(Self.Handle,wm_close,0,0);` in the IIGraph form code, does not close the graph form, so that execution can resume on the main form, for the next iteration of the loop. You have to manually close the graph for it to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep re-using the same instance of each sub-form over and over?

Comment: Your setting of ModalResult have no effect in OnActivate. It is set to mrNone at the beginning of the modal loop (which is after sending an CM_ACTIVATE to the form).

Comment: Im not checking the modal result anyways, so it really is not necessary. What do you mean Jerry?

Comment: Cannot duplicate in a brand new VCL app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you have coded all your business logic in GUI code. So you are not able to execute the code that you want to execute without the convoluted code seen in the question.

If you want to solve your real problem you will deal with the root cause of your woes. You will separate the business logic and the GUI code. You will arrange for your business logic to be able to be executed in the absence of GUI.

If you don't want to solve your real problem, and wish to continue with this madness, you need to post a `WM_CLOSE` message to `frmIIGraph.Handle` in the `OnDeactivate` event handler for `TfrmEventEdit`. Presumably the one you post in `TfrmIIGraph.FormActivate` is getting consumed by the sub-form's message loop, or perhaps some call to `ProcessMessages`. But I cannot endorse this as a sane way to proceed.

Comment: I agree, but I did not write this application, it was written by a large government organization. And we need the UI functioning, as there are visualizations that need to be seen.

Comment: Fine. Post the close message for sub form when sub sub form deactivates.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I know its messy, but its not for a lot of people to use. Internal use. You are a godsend.

Comment: Try using `TThread.Queue(nil, Self.Close)` instead of `PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)`.  Either the `WM_CLOSE` is getting swallowed up, or maybe the Form's `Handle` is being recreated before `WM_CLOSE` is retrieved from the message queue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Have you ever read [codeless code](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/156)?

Comment: @mg30rg I have not. Why do you ask?

Comment: Maybe you should read that particular story. _(It was a joke of some sort.)_